# How can I see the table I created on postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database named `MSK`, under `MSK` there are 3 schemes,

On `MSK`, I right clicked, and selected `SQL Editor` , and wrote this code,

```
create  table city(
    ID VARCHAR(2) primary key,
    code VARCHAR(2) not null,
    name VARCHAR(20) not null
)
```

But when I search city in database, there is no `city`. When i execute that code again, it says the `city` already exists.

I am using Dbeaver 21.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a table without specifying the schema, it is created in the first existing schema on your `search-path`.

To override that default, explicitly specify the schema name:

```
CREATE TABLE mobile.city (...);
```

Comment: Sir, i have a question. Which is better approach to create tables? by writing code like `create table etc` or by using interface like `right click on table, create table etc`

Comment: It is a matter of taste. I personally exclusively use the command line client `psql`, where I only have the former option. I am not a nobleman or a military superior, by the way.